# Sobre datatime genexus

Tags: genexus

trae un Día menos al mostrar en pantalla una fecha de la BD, la única alternativa que encontré es concatenar con YMDTOD y sumarle 1, si existe otra alternativa mas estaría agradecido.

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para asi poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Seguramente se deba a que en la Base de Datos se está guardando en una zona horaria diferente a la de la computadora "cliente" (donde se muestra en pantalla).

Revisa el valor de la propiedad [Date Time storage timezone](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?17218,Date%20Time%20storage%20timezone%20property) en tu Knowledge Base.